# Group Elements Under another element with jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting, grouping, element

I have a list of 100 links of referrers. They are from different cities and I need to group the ones from same city. since my output is created by a CMS it's not static.

imagine a list of 100 different

```
<a href="link">Name</a>
```

I'm planning to add a rel, class or id to specify their cities

```
<a href="link" rel="city">Name</a>
```

I need to group the links from same city and put them in some div

```
City1  
 - link1  
 - link2  
 - link3  
 - link4  

City2  
 - link1  
 - link2  
 - link3
```

some cities have over 20 links some have only 1.

Comment: could you please post an example of your list?

Comment: since you are able to access code to create city attribute... sort them on server at same time

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand exactly your issue, but you can make an array with your links and  check how to sort or [map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) an array with jquery.

Comment: imagine a list of 100 differnt  
<a href="link">Name</a>  
im plannning to add a rel ,class or id to specify their cities  
<a href="link" rel="city">Name</a>  
  
i need to group the links from same city and put them in some div  
  
City1  
     link1  
     link2  
     link3  
     link4  
City2  
     link1  
     link2  
     link3  
  
some cities have over 20 links some have only 1

Comment: @charlieftl
it will take tons of more php code to process this kind of action.
i believe jquery can handle this with 3-4 lines of code tops.

the wrap function might be the one im looking for but im not very familiar with jquery

Comment: Why don't you use each in this case:
$('a').each(function(ind,link){// Process our link here});